# End a WCF Session from the Server?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, microsoft-sync-framework

This may be a shot in the dark (I don't know much about the internals of WCF), but here goes...

I'm currently working with a legacy application at a client site and we're experiencing a persistent issue with a WCF service.  The application is using the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 and syncing through the aforementioned service.  The server-side implementation of the service has a lot of custom code in various states of "a mess."

Anyway, we're seeing an error on the client application most of the time and the pattern we're narrowing down centers around different users using the application on the same machine hitting the same service.  It *seems* that the service and the client are getting out of sync in some way on an authentication level.

The error is discussed in an article [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/690778-messagesecurityexception-when-consuming-wcf-service), and we're currently investigating the approach of switching from message layer security to transport layer security, which will hopefully solve the problem.  However, we may be able to solve it in a less invasive manner if this question makes sense.

In the linked article, one of the suggestions was to forcibly terminate the connection if the specific exception is caught, try again, and if it fails again it wasn't because of this particular theory.  Sounds good, and easy to implement.  However, I find myself unable to say with confidence if the connection is being properly terminated.

The service operates through a custom interface, which is implemented on the server-side.  The only thing that interface can do to end the connection is call `EndSession()` on the proxy itself, which calls `EndSession()` on the server which is a custom method.

So...

From a WCF service method, is there a way to properly and gracefully terminate the connection with the client in a way the client will like?

That is, in this custom `EndSession()` is there some last step I can take to cause the server to completely forget that this connection was open?  Because it *seems* like when another user on the same machine tries to hit the service within the application, that's when it fails with the error in the linked article.

The idea is that, at the client side of things, code which calls `EndSession()` is followed by nulling out the proxy object, then a factory method is called to supply another one the next time it's needed.  So I wonder if something additional needs to happen on the server side (and does by default in WCF were it not for all this custom implementation code) to terminate the connection on that end?

Like I said, a shot in the dark.  But maybe in answers/discussions here I can at least further diagnose the problem, so any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there are only really three ways in which a [session](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,af6e6325-2e30-42e3-acb9-57e1363fa51e.aspx) can terminated

1. The client closes the proxy
2. The service's receiveTimeout is exceeded
   before the client sends another
   request
3. the service throws a
   non-fault exception which will fault
   the channel and so terminate the
   session

if you don't want the client involved then you only have 2 and 3 neither of which end well for the client - they will get an exception in both situation on the next attempt to talk to the service.

You could use [Duplex messaging](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx) and get the service to notify the client that its requires session termination - the client then gets an opportunity to close down the proxy gracefully but this is a cooperative strategy

Comment: Sorry it took a while to get back to this, it's been a hectic week on this project.  I think we're going to look into duplex messaging a bit (though the state of this legacy code doesn't lend itself well to change), I appreciate the suggestion.  But I've at least tested your points on terminations not ending well for the client and you're absolutely right :)  In any event, and for reasons not entirely known to the team, the system is mostly working now.  I think we got the client successfully closing the proxy.  Thanks for the advice!