# how to terminate a wcf session

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, session

WCF Sessions are initiated by attribute

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
```

and terminated by

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
```

Is there a way to terminate the current WCF session based on some condition? Lets say validate credentials else do not let the session start. Is there a way to do this without throwing exception in the operation contract that initiates session.

This is to make sure that the client does not make additional calls once the session is terminated. Probably a limitation within WCF as sessions are client initiated.

Comment: I really don't know the answer to this, but I am wondering: what would you send back to the client?

Comment: I don't have sample code at the moment, but create a class that implements IParameterInspector and throw a custom fault contract in the `BeforeCall` method if your credential validation fails. Document the fault contract in your api. Also, same class, implement `Attribute` so you can simply apply this behavior to any operation or even class.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to terminate the current WCF session based on some
>   condition? Lets say validate credentials else do not let the session
>   start. Is there a way to do this without throwing exception in the
>   operation contract that initiates session.

Base on your code IsInitiating and Isterminating it automatically throw an exception to client once the method was called with

> IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true

without calling the method with

> IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false

And I don't think you can handle it without throwing exception because the WCF works on it under the hood. Or may be their was *"which I'm not aware of"*.

**You may consider few info I wrote below.**

You didn't mention what messaging type you are using in your Service.

- If you are using Duplex messaging you can close/abort the connection without throwing any exception to the client.

And what kind of validation credentials mechanism you implemented?

- If your credential validation use custom UserNamePassword validator I don't think their is a way to terminate it without throwing exception.
- If you are using certificate with credentials I don't think you need to terminate the session because it terminate once authentication is not successful.

> This is to make sure that the client does not make additional calls
>   once the session is terminated. Probably a limitation within WCF as
>   sessions are client initiated.

- If you implemented proper validation of credentials you don't need to worry about "***making sure that the client does not make additional calss...***" because no session initiated at all.

Additional info about different ways to [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364434/end-a-wcf-session-from-the-server) the connection in WCF.