# Wcf How to termiate session in a OperationContract[isInitiating=true]

Tags: wcf

I have an operation contract named "Login" and it has IsInitiating=true flag.

Client sends it's credentials to this function and i need to check credentials and return a message to the client like "Your credentials not correct!" and i must close the session immediately. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it in the same operation, because you cannot use  `IsInitiating=true` and `IsTerminating=true` at same time.

The MSDN shows how to implement both: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isterminating(v=vs.110).aspx)

A possible solution is throw an exception instead of return a message. You can then handle this exception in the client and close the channel.

This how it works "behind the scenes" as MSDN attests:

> In a client application, a value of IsTerminating set to true instructs WCF to close the channel after the reply arrives.

There is another question about how to end a session on server side that can help you: [end-a-wcf-session-from-the-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364434/end-a-wcf-session-from-the-server)